# Trouble creating multiline regex

Tags: java, regex

I am doing some data cleaning job where i have to convert pdf file into text using (iText). I need to extract some Data tables out from the parsed. (Tables can appear in any order so could not parse it line by line). Anyways i started looking into regex solution for the same which i thought would be easier but apparently not for me.

The data looks like this

```
Dummy Value Data
VAL1 VAL2 Mean Calc  Calc2
(mf) (m) (rad) (rad) (rad/100m)
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000
9224.0 9224.0 0.0 0.0 0.000
9928.0 9925.9 2.3 322.5 0.490
9885.0 9889.8 0.9 285.9 -0.953
5432.0 5432.5 3.3 95.4 -0.509
<newline>
<newline>
```

This is exactly the same patter i want to capture. The last 2 new lines mark the end of the pattern.
I did tried a few things but nothing worked. I can share my regex too but they dont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find method

Your regex would be

```
(?<VAL1>[-+]?\d+([.]\d+)?)\s+(?<VAL2>[-+]?\d+([.]\d+)?)\s+(?<Mean>[-+]?\d+([.]\d+)?)\s+(?<Calc>[-+]?\d+([.]\d+)?)\s+(?<Calc2>[-+]?\d+([.]\d+)?)
```

Your code

```
Matcher m=Pattern.compile(aboveRegex).matcher();
while(m.find())
{
    m.group("VAL1");
    m.group("VAL2");
    m.group("Mean");
    m.group("Calc");
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To match multiple such tables

```
([+-]?\d+([.]\d+)?( [+-]?\d+([.]\d+)?){4}(\r?\n))+(?=(\r?\n))
```

Comment: I believe that will try and capture the 4  numbers values in each line. The intention is to have something like "Dummy* \n\n"

Comment: The regex you provided works fine. But there are multiple tables of similar kind (similar meaning 5 numbers in a line). i tried the same approach before but doesnt solve the problem i am having

Comment: @BhanuKaushik so you want to capture multiple tables ending with two newlines..not values

Comment: True. The tables start with different names.

Comment: No It does not capture anything.

Comment: @BhanuKaushik its working [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=6cc0dba4-8875-4089-8a20-59a943db4bf5)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32848/discussion-between-bhanu-kaushik-and-anirudh)

Answer (score 0):

Try the next regex:

```
(\w+( +\w+)*)\r?\n(\w+( +\w+)*)\r?\n(\([\w/]+\)( \([\w/]+\))*)\r?\n((-?\d+\.\d+( -?\d+\.\d+)* *)\r?\n)*(?=(\r?\n){2})
```

The *`<newline>`* is `\r?\n` in the regex.

Comment: @Paul-- I am trying to filter out this table from similar but different tables from a huge text
Ideally i need to capture "Dummy `Any thing in between` \n\n". I am not sure whether it is doable or not.

Comment: No It does not capture anything in my data set.

Comment: Nop. I am using gskinner and regexhero to test it.